# Bi-directional sync between mysql and mongodb using cdc

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc, mongodb-kafka-connector

Basically I want to achieve bi-directional sync between mysql and mongodb through cdc.

The structure of table in mysql is

```
CREATE TABLE `booking_journal_thinclient` (`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`amount` double DEFAULT NULL,`booking_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`destination_station` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`journey_date` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,`last_modified` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,`number_of_passengers` int DEFAULT NULL,`source_station` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`ticket_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,`train_number` int DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`),UNIQUE KEY `UK_n9sqoiwbptmpp6ojrtywpu2fr` (`ticket_number`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I have used debezium mysql source connector to transfer data from mysql to mongo using cdc. The sample document that gets stored in mongodb is

```
{"_id": {"id": 1},"amount": 8500,"booking_status": "BOOKED","destination_station": "Mumbai",
"journey_date": {"$date": "2023-03-20T20:15:48.175Z"},"last_modified": {"$date": "2023-03-20T20:15:48.175Z"},"number_of_passengers": 4,"source_station": "Howrah","ticket_number": "fcf1ef67-1900-41b1-95d4-59c61e80363a","train_number": null}
```

Now I want to write a debezium mongodb source connector and jdbc sink connector to establish bi-directional sink. The configuration of mongodb-source connector is

```
{
    "name": "mongodb-source-connector",
    "config" : {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "mongodb.hosts": "debezium/localhost:27017",
    "mongodb.name": "production",

    "mongodb.user": "sudhir",
    "mongodb.password": "password",
    "database.include.list" : "uts_production_kafkaconnect",
    "collection.include.list": "uts_production_kafkaconnect.booking_journal_production",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka:9092",
    "key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "transforms": "unwrap,route",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState",
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.route.regex": "(\[^.\]+)\\\\.(\[^.\]+)\\\\.(\[^.\]+)",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "$3"
    }
}
```

After uploading it messages gets published in topic "booking_journal_production",
The value part of message is

{"schema": {"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "double","optional": true,"field": "amount"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "booking_status"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "destination_station"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp","version": 1,"field": "journey_date"},{"type": "int64","optional": true,"name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp","version": 1,"field": "last_modified"},{"type": "int32","optional": true,"field": "number_of_passengers"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "source_station"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "ticket_number"},{"type": "string","optional": true,"field": "train_number"},{"type": "struct","fields": [{"type": "int32","optional": true,"field": "id"}],"optional": true,"name": "production.uts_production_kafkaconnect.booking_journal_production.id","field": "id"}],"optional": false,"name": "production.uts_production_kafkaconnect.booking_journal_production"},"payload": {"amount": 1000,"booking_status": "BOOKED","destination_station": "Patiala","journey_date": 1680278554279,"last_modified": 1680278554279,"number_of_passengers": 10,"source_station": "New Delhi","ticket_number": "eba7f80e-c61d-4290-a0aa-a54f6bc65c2b","train_number": null,"id": {"id": 8}}}

The Key part of message is

Struct{id=Struct{id=8}}

The JDBC sink connector I am using to save the message in mysql table is

```
{
    "name": "mysql-sink-connector-1",
    "config" : {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "topics": "test",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/uts_thinclient_kafkaconnect?user=root&password=password&useSSL=false",
    "auto.create": true,
    "auto.evolve": true,

    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "table.name.format": "uts_thinclient_kafkaconnect.booking_journal_thinclient",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "id",
    "delete.enabled": true,
    "delete.retention.ms": 3600000,
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": true,
    "errors.log.include.messages": true,
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "dlq.topic",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": true,
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor": 1,
    "db.timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
}    
}
```

The jdbc sink connector I made is:-

```
{
    "name": "mysql-sink-connector-1",
    "config" : {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "topics": "booking_journal_production",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/uts_thinclient_kafkaconnect?user=root&password=password&useSSL=false",
    "auto.create": true,
    "auto.evolve": true,

    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "table.name.format": "uts_thinclient_kafkaconnect.booking_journal_thinclient",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "id",
    "delete.enabled": true,
    "delete.retention.ms": 3600000,
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.log.enable": true,
    "errors.log.include.messages": true,
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "dlq.topic",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": true,
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor": 1,
    "db.timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
    }    
}
```

The error message shown is

```
ERROR Error encountered in task mysql-sink-connector-1-0. Executing stage 'TASK_PUT' with class 'org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkTask', where consumed record is {topic='booking_journal_production', partition=0, offset=0, timestamp=1681829168637, timestampType=CreateTime}.
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter:66)java.sql.SQLException: Exception chain:java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect integer value: 'Struct{id=Struct{id=1}}' for column 'id' at row 1java.sql.SQLException:
 Incorrect integer value: 'Struct{id=Struct{id=1}}' for column 'id' at row 1
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.getAllMessagesException(JdbcSinkTask.java:159)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.unrollAndRetry(JdbcSinkTask.java:145)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:117)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:586)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
[2023-04-18 20:36:56,597] INFO creating interceptor (io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor:74)[2023-04-18 20:36:56,598] INFO MonitoringInterceptorConfig values:confluent.monitoring.interceptor.publishMs = 15000confluent.monitoring.interceptor.topic = _confluent-monitoring(io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringInterceptorConfig:361)
```

Please help. Thanks